# can anyone tell me the mime type of the playReady?

Tags: android, playready

Now, I am using the method acquireDrmInfo of DRM to get Dmr info.But I don't know the mime type of playReady.
can anyone tell me?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PlayReady is a DRM system rather than a media type, just in case that is not clear.

It supports encrypting content and sharing the keys of the encrypted content between a server and a client.

So a mp4 video with MIME type video/mp4 may be encrypted and the DRM system being used PlayReady, but the video MIME type will remain the same as for an unencrypted copy of the video - there is information within the video headers that let the client know it is encrypted.

The PlayReady DRM communication between the client and the server is typically REST based using standard HTTP requests and responses.